# how to put two text inputs values to hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

**My HTML:**

```
   <li style="display: none;">
    <span class="add-on"></span>
    <input class="" type="text" value="" style="display: none;">
    <input class="" type="hidden" name="BIOLOGY" value="" style="display: none;">
    <input class="datepicker" type="date">
    </li>

    <li>
    <span class="add-on">Ecconomics</span>
    <input class="Ecconomics" type="text" value="">
    <input class="Ecconomics" type="hidden" name="ECONOMICS" value="">
    <input class="datepicker" type="date">
    </li>

    <li>
     <span class="add-on">Business Study</span>
     <input class="Business Study" type="text" value="">
     <input class="Business Study" type="hidden" name="BUSINESS STUDIES" value="">
     <input class="datepicker" type="date">
   </li>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
    var getDate = $(".datepicker").val();
    var getMark = $("li > span + input").val();
    var plusVal = getDate + getMark;

    $(".picker").val(plusVal);

});
```

I want to put .`datepicker` class value and first text input value to hidden input value using JavasScript/jQuery. I was trying to do it using the above code but no luck. I have many `<li>` tags which contain above 3 inputs **TEXT, HIDDEN and DATEPICKER**. How do I do that?

Comment: @Dilini Could you provide more details?

Comment: Above my jquery is worked for one li element content which contain 3 inputs.I want to put getDate,getMark value to hidden input which contain middle of the 3 inputs

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each Li element and grab the inputs inside, something like:

```
$('li').each(function(){
  var self= $(this);
  var getDate= self.find('.datepicker').val();
  var getMark= self.find('span + input').val();
  var plusVal = getDate + getMark;

  self.find('.datepicker').val(plusVal);
})
```

It's not optimized or tested. But you get the idea.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but you can try it and ref your fiddle here.

Comment: @DiliniWasana : I think you should be testing it , not c2

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
jQuery('li input[type=text]').keyup(function(e){
       var getMark = jQuery(this).val();
       var li = jQuery(this).closest('li');
       var getDate = li.find('.datepicker').val();
       var Hfield = li.find('input[type=hidden]');
       Hfield.val(getMark + getDate);
    });
```